# Accessing service on Windows from WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, xdebug, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to send Xdebug info to vs code on Windows from my WSL2 Ubuntu install but can not seem to get access to port 9000 on Windows from WSL2.

Is this just something that's not allowed?

Comment: Your description is a bit wrong: you are NOT connecting to Xdebug: it's Xdebug that connects to debug client (IDE or editor, e.g. VSCode/PhpStorm/NetBeans etc).

Comment: Other than that: it's an issue with getting the right IP (how it can connect from WSL into your host OS). Check https://www.silverf0x00.com/setting-up-xdebug-for-phpstorm-on-windows-wsl2/ or search for other articles that could be specific to your editor: https://www.google.com/search?q=Xdebug+with+WSL2

Comment: What is interesting is that even with using the docs from microsoft it still is not working correctly.

Comment: Sorry, not using WSL myself so cannot give any better advice. I personally prefer either real VM or Docker (for me they worked just fine, no major issues; Xdebug worked just fine).